# Personalizar "prepopulation" en Django admin

Tags: javascript, python, django

Actualmente tengo un campo que automáticamente se llena tomando el valor de dos campos adicionales en orden: equipo 1 y equipo dos.

Obtengo el siguiente resultado con este còdigo dentro de la clase Administrador correspondiente al modelo Match:

```
@admin.register(Match)
class MatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"fixture": ("team_1", "team_2")}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente me pone Equipo1-Equipo2, pero necesito que el formato sea Equipo1 vs Equipo2, automàticamente tiene que quedar de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, el campo `fixture`va se autocompleta con la concatenaciòn de las cadenas `team_1`+ vs + `team_2`, de forma que por ejemplo, `team_1`es Brasil y `team_2`es Argentina, `fixture`se autocompleta còmo `Brasil vs Argentina`.

Existe alguna forma de conseguirlo? De que forma podrìa hacerlo?

Comment: No se ven las imágenes, pero puedes usar [`toUpperCase`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp).

Comment: @toledano, en que parte uso esa instrucciòn?

Comment: Oh, ya que editaste tu código, pues corrige el método `__str__` o `__unicode__` de tu modelo.

Comment: No entiendo que tiene que ver ese mètodo con autocompletar el campo `fixture`con una concatenaciòn de `team_1`vs `team_2`.

Comment: El problema es que `prepopulated_fields` sirve para trabajar con campos de tipo slug y reemplaza los espacios en blanco por guiones, me parece que esto se hace mediante JavaScript. Para modificarlo tendrías que crear tu propia forma de hacerlo